# Question about installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, internet, swap, restricted

I have 3 questions about installing ubuntu Please help Me.

1. How much space I have to give to swap partition? My ram is 8GB.
2. We check two options when installing Ubuntu (one is mp3 fluendo plugin and the other is about restricted extras). Does Ubuntu need internet connection to install them during installation?
3. Is it recommended to have internet connection during installation?
   Can i download and install everything that Ubuntu downloads during installation later? How?

Comment: Use 2GB for swap. You probably never will use it. And with newer system you will not see much advantage with hibernating. It boots fast anyway, not like Windows which has to hibernate to boot fast. If you really want hibernation you need 8GiB (not 8GB). https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is an argued question, but my opinion is that with 8 or more GB of RAM you don't need swap unless you use suspend to disk. If you are sure you need swap it should be at least the size of your RAM.
2. I don't know if they are downloaded or installed from your installation media, but you can install them any time you want later from the corresponding packages (i.e. the ubuntu-restricted-extras meta package and its dependencies).
3. You can install all the updates later via the regular updates procedure. However I believe that it's better to download and install them during the system installation process as it might prevent some bugs.